# how to get category list in product page?

Tags: php, smarty

I am working on cs-cart for online shopping

how can i get category list in product page

Thanks.

Comment: @boisvert , categories that r related to that product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your products data.

If you have a data table,

```
prod_id prod_more categ
-----------------------
1        ...      book
(more rows)
```

To display all products, you run the query

```
        select * from product
```

then loop through the results.

To display all categories, do a different query

```
        select distinct categ from product
```

then adapt the loop slightly.

There are lots of code samples that explain how to do this, e.g. on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php)

Comment: boisvert , this is not the core PHP man if u gone through code of cs-cart then u will come to know that its smarty .

Comment: even simpler then. Selecting the data that you choose to display still applies. Sorry if link isn't helpful.

Comment: there is some standard method to create this procedure in cs-cart and i am stuck with that

Comment: Edit your question to make it clear. Try and say something of why you're stuck and what you've tried to do about it. If your question becomes clearer, more purposeful I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Click Design - > Blocks and make sure you have a block on the left sidebar that is Active to show the Categories. And be sure you have categories that are active with active products that can be purchased so the price is set and inventory/ordering options are set correctly.